# SharePoint - cannot change users e-mail address (SIP address?)

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, 2016, ad

We have a SharePoint user (SP2016 on prem) and we need to change his email address. SharePoint user profile is up to date with the correct email address. But when I click on the user within a SharePoint site the old address is still there. Looking into the html there is a property "sip" with the wrong (old) email address and when he's using list notifications it send emails to the wrong address.

I did find a powershell script, "`set-spuser -SyncFromAD`" but it doesn't work. I guess there are som sync problem with AD vs site user list (every site has it's own copy of it if I'm correct). Looking in the users user profile the sip address is all good. How do I change this users email address?

Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Run thsi command in sharepoint pwoershell and check the last sync date of each db:  stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit the site and modify the URL in your browser. Append

```
/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx
```

to the site url.

Example:

```
https://sharepoint.tld/sites/yoursite/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx
```

In this hidden list you can see all user related stored information. Find your user and delete him. The next time he visits the site his recent information should be added automatically to that list.

Comment: You are welcome!